# How to bind function as a property of object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, function-binding

I have a function which takes an object property, in this object I want to pass a function as one of the properties. I will like to execute the function when the property is called. I need to bind the function as the this context is lost before the function will be executed.

```
    var myfunction = function () {
       console.log("Something");
    }

    // this works
    this.HeaderService.setState({
      leftButton: {
        click: this.myfunction.bind(this)
      }
    });

    // can't get this to work
    const self = this;
    this.HeaderService.setState({
      leftButton: {
        click() {
           return (function () {
              console.log("something");
           }).bind(this)
        }
      }
    })
```

I can get the function expression to work, but I cant get the second case where I want to define the function as the value of the property click. How do i do this?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can't use just define click as an arrow function? e.g. `click: () => console.log("someting")`

Comment: What exactly is the problem with what you have now? Can you show how you want your final object to look?

Comment: the problem I have now is in the second case the function is never called, i.e something is never logged

Comment: @JaimeTorres tried the arrow function and it achieves what I want, thanks!

Comment: You have `const self = this;`, but are not using `self` anywhere. I assume you meant to use `.bind(self)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing what @JamieTorres suggested an arrow function fixes the issue

```
 const self = this;
   this.HeaderService.setState({
      leftButton: {
        click: () => {
           return (function () {
              console.log("something");
           }).bind(this)
        }
      }
    })
```